# Node.js async parallel not working how it should be?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I've got multiple `promise`' that I want to run one after the other, and I'm not sure I want to be returning the promises as it gets pretty messy!

So I decided to use the `async` library and implement the `parallel` method. Now I noticed that all my promises weren't running one, after the other, instead they were doing what promises are suppose todo (run + finish whenever).

I noticed that all the console.logs were running before all the promises were finished.

```
async.parallel([
        (cb) => {
          console.log ("hi")
            grabMeData (Args)
              .then ( (data) => {

                // The promise is done and now I want to goto the next functio
                cb();
              }).catch(()=>console.log('err'));
        },
        (callback) => {
          // The above promise is done, and I'm the callback
          Query.checkUserExists()
          .then ( () => {
            if (Query.error) {
              console.log (Query.error); // Determine error here
              return; // Return to client if needed
            }
            callback();
          });
        },
        () => {
          // The above promise is done and I'm the callback!

          // Originally wanted to be async
          if (Query.accAlreadyCreated) {
            this.NewUserModel.user_id = Query.user_id;
            this.generateToken();
          } else {
            console.log ("account not created");
          }
          console.log ('xx')
        }
    ], () =>{
      console.log ("finished async parallel")
    });
```

Any reason why my callbacks are being run `before` the promises are resolved (.then).

Comment: If you're trying to run these functions in order, then async.parallel is not the API you need, you should try async.waterfall

Comment: Ahhhhh okay @StephenCrosby Thanks

Comment: With promises, you should not use `async.js` at all. Just chain them using `then`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like Bergi said, `async.js` is redundant when you use promise, your code can be simplified as:

```
console.log('hi')
grabMeData(Args)
  .catch(e => console.error(e))
  .then(() => Query.checkUserExists())
  .then(() => {
    if (Query.accAlreadyCreated) {
      this.NewUserModel.user_id = Query.user_id
      return this.generateToken()
    } 
    console.log ("account not created")   
  })
  .then(() => console.log ('xx')  )
```

Comment: You're 100% right...Not sure why I was thinking to use the async package.